# Display errors on screen but disable file logging

Tags: php

Is there a way to display the errors from PHP but disable them in the log files?

I currently have this:

```
// Log all errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Display none
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

What's the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `php.ini` file, to stop errors being reported into the log file turn `log_errors = Off`

```
; Besides displaying errors, PHP can also log errors to locations such as a
; server-specific log, STDERR, or a location specified by the error_log
; directive found below. While errors should not be displayed on productions
; servers they should still be monitored and logging is a great way to do that.
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: On
; http://php.net/log-errors
log_errors = Off
```

While making sure that `display_errors` is on

```
; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; For production environments, we recommend logging errors rather than
; sending them to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On
```

Comment: nice ;) it was exactly that I was looking for. Thank you! and the good part is that both are configurable using `ini_set()` function

Answer (score 1):

edit file - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

from this :

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common
ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

to this :

```
#CustomLog logs/access_log common
#ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

Comment: This will disable all errors regardless its of php or apache besides you are also suppressing your access_log :(